# how to set ComponentName?

Tags: android

I want to sendBroadcast to other app,
the app package is **com.android.cci**
the class is in folder engtest and name as FtmEngButtons,
so which **ComponentName** setting should be correct

1. `ComponentName("com.android.cci", "com.android.cci.engtest.FtmEngButtons");`
2. `ComponentName("com.android.cci.engtest", "FtmEngButtons");`
3. `ComponentName("com.android.cci", "com.android.cci.FtmEngButtons");`
4. `ComponentName("com.android.cci.engtest", "com.android.cci.engtest.FtmEngButtons");`
5. or others?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the documentation provided for `ComponentName`, it states that "Two pieces of information, encapsulated here, are required to identify a component: the package (a String) it exists in, and the class (a String) name inside of that package."

So, in this `ComponentName` constructor, the first argument is not the package name of the class but rather the package name of the application.

Based on this, the first option is the correct one -- 
`ComponentName("com.android.cci", "com.android.cci.engtest.FtmEngButtons");`

For Reference -- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html